# Azure JSON Response Deserialization C#

Tags: c#, json, azure, deserialization

My JSON Response is shown below,

```
[
 {
  "faceRectangle": {
     "top": 214,
     "left": 472,
     "width": 450,
     "height": 450
  },
  "faceAttributes": {
     "age": 19.0,
     "emotion": {
        "anger": 0.0,
        "contempt": 0.0,
        "disgust": 0.0,
        "fear": 0.0,
        "happiness": 0.0,
        "neutral": 0.996,
        "sadness": 0.003,
        "surprise": 0.001
     }
   }
 }
]
```

My C# class is as follows:

```
public class Output
{
    public List<FaceRectangle> FaceRectangles { get; set; }
    public List<FaceAttribute> faceAttributes { get; set; }
}
public class FaceAttribute
{
    public List<Emotion> Emotions { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
public class Emotion { 
    public float anger { get; set; }
    public float contempt { get; set; }
    public float disgust { get; set; }
    public float fear { get; set; }
    public float happiness { get; set; }
    public float neutral { get; set; }
    public float sadness { get; set; }
    public float surprise { get; set; }
}
public class FaceRectangle
{
    public int top { get; set; }
    public int left { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I am trying to deserialize the above response, I am getting the following error.
Error code is shown as "Not supported for deserialization of an array"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzUM4.png)

Can anyone help me with this?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you log format.GetType()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using these classes created from [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/):

```
public class FaceRectangle
{
    public int Top { get; set; }
    public int Left { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}

public class Emotion
{
    public double Anger { get; set; }
    public double Contempt { get; set; }
    public double Disgust { get; set; }
    public double Fear { get; set; }
    public double Happiness { get; set; }
    public double Neutral { get; set; }
    public double Sadness { get; set; }
    public double Surprise { get; set; }
}

public class FaceAttributes
{
    public double Age { get; set; }
    public Emotion Emotion { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public FaceRectangle FaceRectangle { get; set; }
    public FaceAttributes FaceAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize your JSON Array response into `List<RootObject` using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json) NuGet Package:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

...

var json = @"[{""faceRectangle"": {""top"": 214,""left"": 472,""width"": 450,""height"": 450},""faceAttributes"": {""age"": 19.0,""emotion"": {""anger"": 0.0,""contempt"": 0.0,""disgust"": 0.0,""fear"": 0.0,""happiness"": 0.0,""neutral"": 0.996,""sadness"": 0.003,""surprise"": 0.001}}}]";

var deserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
```